# regex pattern for numeric value which starts either from 9 or 8

Tags: regex, xsd

I need your help for forming a regex pattern for XSD.

As of now,in my .net project,a input for a field can be of 7 digit which can start from 0 to 9
or input can be of 8 digit which cant start with 0.

we are using

```
<xs:pattern value="[1-9]?[0-9]{7}" />
```

to address this pattern.

Now, as per new requirement,we have to make modification so that input can accept
8 digit which cant start with 0 or input can be of 9 digit which can start from 1,2,3,4 only.

i tried

```
 <xs:pattern value="[1-4]?[1-9]?[0-9]{7}" />
```

but its giving me error while i use 100000000,200000000 like value.
in short its not accepting 0 at second place and that is due to incorrect pattern

could you please guide me in this matter.

Comment: Depending on the time you have to invest in this, I suggest this site to learn about regular expressions in general, it may be able to improve your understanding to the point where you can formulate your own regex: https://regexone.com/

Comment: You should add a newline before the code for it to display correctly.

Comment: Try `value="[1-9][0-9]{7}|[1-4][0-9]{8}"`. `[1-9][0-9]{7}` alternative matches `1` to `9` and then 7 digits. `[1-4][0-9]{8}` matches `1` to `4` and then any 8 digits.

Comment: I changed the `.net` tag to the relevant `xsd` one.

Comment: Also, a good site to use when constructing regular expressions: http://regex101.com. I've setup a testcase for you here: https://regex101.com/r/v1rhp3/3 (note: it uses `^` and `$` for the multiline input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we have to make modification so that input can accept 8 digit which cant start with 0 or input can be of 9 digit which can start from 1,2,3,4 only

You may use

```
value="[1-9][0-9]{7}|[1-4][0-9]{8}"
```

**Details**

- `[1-9][0-9]{7}` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 7 digits
- `|` - or
- `[1-4][0-9]{8}` - a digit from `1` to `4` and then any 8 digits

XSD regex patterns are anchored by default, so this should be enough.

Comment: All true.  But the last point is perhaps understated.  XSD patterns are not just anchored by default; there is no other way to use them.  XSD regexes match against the entire string, period.  They are anchored, one might say, *by definition*.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen I used the "anchored by default" wording specifically for those who are not familiar with XML Schema regex, but who know PCRE, JS, Python, Java, .NET regex flavors to avoid meaningless downvotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - point taken.  No criticism intended; understatement is not always a mistake.  I was only thinking of readers who see the word  'default' and wonder how one overrides the default.